# Initialize Property of Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface, initialization

I have read multiple posts but haven't found an appropriate answer for my problem.
But there has to be one. So please be patient if this post really is an duplicate.

I try to initialize a Property of a generic type implementing a generic interface.

My interface looks basically like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<TType> : IMyInterface
{
    TType Value {get; set;}

    // ... and some more ...
}

public interface IMyInterface 
{
    SetValue(string value);
}
```

I have multiple Classes implementing `IMyInterface` without knowing them
at the piece of code, where I need to set the value.

Is it possible to inizialize the "Value"-Property without using the Name of the property?
(Is there a "nice" way to do this?) - It isn't possible to use `SetValue< TType >`

```
void SetValue(object obj, string value)
{
    // object obj implements IMyInterface<???>
    PropertyInfo valueInfo = typeof(obj).GetType().GetProperty("Value")
    valueInfo.SetValue(obj, Activator.CreateInstance(valueInfo.PropertyType))

    ((IMyInterface)obj).SetValue(value);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: - removed -

EDIT 2:

This structure is given:

```
public Interface IGeneric<TType> : INonGeneric
{
    TType Value2 {get;}
}

public Interface INonGeneric
{
    object Value1 {get;}
}
```

using "Value1" from reflection is really easy:

```
INonGeneric myObject = (INonGeneric)givenObject;
doSomething(myObject.Value1)
```

if i need to access "Value2" it isn't that easy. As one can see in my first example I had to use the following construct which not seems to be the best way to access "Value2", because the properties name is hardcoded.

```
PropertyInfo valueInfo = givenObject.GetType().GetProperty("Value2");
object value = (object)valueInfo.GetValue(givenObject);
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: What if your class implements multiple `IMyInterface<T>` like `class Sample : IMyInterface<int>, IMyInterface<string>`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If `TType` is not `string`, what is the code supposed to do? If the object implements only `IMyInterface` and not `IMyInterface<TType>`, what is the code supposed to do? And what _specifically_ do you mean by "initialize"? Your code example seems to try to set the property to some default value/instance, but what if the type does not have a parameterless constructor? I disagree that "there has to be" an answer to your problem, even if you can figure out a way to articulate the problem in a useful way. Some problems are unsolvable (often for good reason).

Comment: Why don't the classes implementing the `IMyInterface<TType>` use the constructor to initialize the value, so you can even for a constructor injection that can be done automatically via Unity kind of IOC library

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - The problem is, that TType can be a complex Type which doesn't exist at compiletime of my library. I only know that TType implements IMyInterface<...>

Comment: @PeterDuniho TType is not string. That's why there is a function called <code>SetValue</code> which parses the string value into TType. Maybe this function should ensure that <code>Value != null</code>. The parameterless constructor is given. Inizialize means that, if TType is e.g. <code>IPAddress</code> I need to create an IPAddress-Object before I can set the value of it.

Comment: @saravanan it would be possible that the constructor initializes the value, yes. I triedto solve the problem using reflection since there was no problem without an generic Interface to set the value. I can't understand why it seems to be impossible if I have an generic interface. That's why I'm asking. If there really is no better solution, I'll have to change the "SetValue"-Method to ensure the Value is initialized.

Comment: Sorry, you're not making any sense. The `IPAddress` type is immutable; it has no parameterless constructor, and even if it did, you couldn't do any further initialization to it after creating an instance. In any case, you haven't shown anything that parses anything, nor explained how the parsing is supposed to interact with the generic interface. It simply is not clear at all what your question is here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho then just use <code>SecureString</code> as example. I really don't want to discuss if this piece of code makes sense or not. I want to know how to deal with generic interfaces and their generic types. The Question really is "how can i use the <code>Value</code>-Property?" It's not just how to initialize. Maybe I need the read the value? How can I access <code>Value</code> without using the name of the Property.

Comment: Sorry. Like it or not, the question "How can I access `Value` without using the name of the Property" just does not make any sense. At some point, if you want the value of a specific property, you have to know its name. And you really should not think you can get a useful answer using a code example that doesn't make sense. Again, whether you want to discuss it or not, a code example that doesn't make sense offers no insight to readers as to what you're asking.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'll give you an other example. See Edit 2.

Comment: @myst3rium Please try to explain the problem you want to solve, what you try to do here seems to lack some basic understanding of generics.

Comment: @Console Of course I have a lack of knowledge. That's why I'm asking ;-) - Okay. I had to deal with this problem beacause I'm currently writing an specific XmlSerializer. Therefore I need to read and set values. For this case I fixed my problem letting my Set-function assure, that "Value" is initialized if neccessary instead of simply assingning the value. But the question stays: Why is there no other solution than hardcoding property names if I use generic Interfaces?

Comment: Thanks @ all for your answers. I'm sorry that I couldn't explain what my problem really was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got you right you have and instance that implements IGeneric, and you want to access the property Value2 (which has a generic return type).

The thing is, Generics are for compile time type safety. You cannot cast your object to IGeneric<...> if you don't know the type parameter. So why do you want to use Generics anyway if you don't know the type parameter?

There is a solution for this "problem", it is the same as IEnumerable and IEnumerable< T> uses. it can look something like this:

```
public interface INonGeneric
{
    object Value {get; }
}

public interface IGeneric<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Magic : INonGeneric, IGeneric<string>
{
    object INonGeneric.Value { get { return this.Value; } }
    public string Value { get { return "test"; } }
}
```

You can now use cast the Object to INonGeneric if you don't use the type parameter, or use the Generic implementation if you know the type parameter at compile time.

But if you want to access a property of a generic type (you have no control over) without knowing the type parameter you will not get around either reflection or dynamic.

The dynamic solution can look like this:

```
dynamic generic = givenObject;
object value2 = generic.Value2;
```

Comment: And if i choose to use reflection there is no other way than hardcoding the properties name?

Comment: @myst3rium you can dynamically iterate through all properties but if you want exactly the one property, there is no other way. Maybe you try to solve something already supported by some XmlSerializer / DataContractSerializer.

Comment: I would use them but the XmlSerializer has some restrictions. E.G. i'd like to load/save complex types, lists etc. - Normally I need a layer in between transforming the serialized values into the objects I need (IPAddress, FileInfo, ....). I decided to write my own serializer which creates the objects I need. As example: Dict<string, List<SecureString>>. - Since I had similar problems while dealing with generics I thank you a lot for your answer. The two ways of dealing with it (IEnumerable-Implementation / dynamic) look very interesting and I'll have a closer look at them soon. Thanks a lot!